# JACK issues on Lubuntu, any thoughts? "Driver is not running"

Tags: jack

I am trying to set up JACK and Wine to run FL Studio on Lubuntu.

Upon running qjackctl and attempting to start JACK, I get the following error.

Any thoughts? I disabled JACK D-Bus and got fewer errors.

```
13:34:12.958 Patchbay deactivated.
13:34:12.958 Statistics reset.
13:34:12.962 ALSA connection change.
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
13:34:12.969 ALSA connection graph change.
13:34:14.262 JACK is starting...
13:34:14.263 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:I82801AAICH -r44100 -p1024 -n2
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
13:34:14.292 JACK was started with PID=1809.
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:I82801AAICH|hw:I82801AAICH|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Using ALSA driver ICH running on card 0 - Intel 82801AA-ICH with STAC9700,83,84 at irq 21
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
13:34:21.390 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Server communication error. Please check the messages window for more info.
JackPosixProcessSync::LockedTimedWait error usec = 5000000 err = Connection timed out
Driver is not running
Cannot create new client
Cannot open qjackctl client
Unknown request 4294967295
CheckSize error size = 0 Size() = 12
CheckRead error
Gtk-Message: (for origin information, set GTK_DEBUG): failed to retrieve property `GtkRange::activate-slider' of type `gboolean' from rc file value "((GString*) 0xf52b40)" of type `GString'
Gtk-Message: (for origin information, set GTK_DEBUG): failed to retrieve property `GtkRange::activate-slider' of type `gboolean' from rc file value "((GString*) 0xf13880)" of type `GString'
13:34:35.841 JACK is stopping...
Jack main caught signal 15
```

Comment: please post output of `aplay -l`